# Does anyone have access to my iFrame App that I build for a page?

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm new to facebook app dev.

I habe built a basic app for iFrame and was able to push it to my page.

However, the app seems to be public. Can anyone push my content to his page?

If so, can I prevent this in my script (that lies on my server).

If not: Where are the restrictions to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: [How to tell which Facebook Page my Page Tab App is installed on](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7623848/how-to-tell-which-facebook-page-my-page-tab-app-is-installed-on/7623969#7623969) - it explains how to determine the page your app is installed on